# Cqlsh doesn't support 24bit console color

Tags: colors, cassandra, cqlsh

After updating my machine to the windows anniversary update which now supports [24-bit](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/09/22/24-bit-color-in-the-windows-console/) color, cqlsh is producing mangled output. Prior it was working fine.

The codepage is 65001 which is UTF. This helped before the update.

Output from logging in and selecting rows:

```
C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\Utils\cassandra\bin>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\Utils\cassandra\bin>cqlsh -u xyz --cqlversion=3.4.0 -C Cassandra-dev01.xyz.local
Password:
Connected to [0;1;34mxyz Development[0m at cassandra-dev01.xyz.local:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.11.1485 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
xyz@cqlsh> use "xyz";
xyz@cqlsh:xyz> select * from "DatabaseSetting" limit 1;

 [0;1;31mName[0m                                 | [0;1;35mValue[0m
--------------------------------------+-------
 [0;1;33mcc38d7f8-821f-491e-8451-530c42ff61fc[0m |   [0;1;33mxyz[0m

(1 rows)
xyz@cqlsh:xyz>
```

Comment: Can you please open up an issue on the Apache Cassandra bug tracker at: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA ?

Comment: Issue created at: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13134